# Trouble getting divs to toggle with data-parent with Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 here.

What I want to happen is that clicking one of the links in the navbars will toggle the content for that link while closing any other one that is open. What I currently have is that each section/div that gets toggled stays shown unless I toggle it to hidden before clicking the next link.

I'm getting that I likely need to add some jQuery to hide all divs right before opening the last clicked, but I haven't been able to get any of the examples that seem to be related to me to work.

I have monkeyed with something like this with no luck:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.collapse').not($(this)).collapse('hide');
})
```

Part of my problem might be understanding where the jQuery script needs to be in my html.

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrLgEE

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello, World</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home" data-parent="#display_data"><img src="home.png" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#chapter1" data-parent="#display_data">Chapter 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#chapter2" data-parent="#display_data">Chapter 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#chapter3" data-parent="#display_data">Chapter 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<br/>

<div id="display_data">
    <div id="home" class="collapse toggle show" data-parent="#display_data">
      Ideally, each toggle closes any shown sections so there is only one "chapter" open at a time
    </div>

    <div id="chapter1" class="collapse toggle">
      This is Chapter 1
    </div>

    <div id="chapter2" class="collapse toggle">
      This is Chapter 2
    </div>

    <div id="chapter3" class="collapse toggle">
      This is Chapter 3
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your script seems to be working as intended.

However, you do not need additional javascript to achieve what you want. If you define the `data-parent` attribute on all collapsible items, then all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when this collapsible item is shown. This is feature is documented at the [Collapse component](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#options).

Here is a working snippet:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home" data-parent="#display_data"><img src="home.png" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#chapter1" data-parent="#display_data">Chapter 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#chapter2" data-parent="#display_data">Chapter 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#chapter3" data-parent="#display_data">Chapter 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<br/>

<div id="display_data">
    <div id="home" class="collapse toggle show" data-parent="#display_data">
      Ideally, each toggle closes any shown sections so there is only one "chapter" open at a time
    </div>

    <!-- Note `data-parent="#display_data"` on these tags too -->
    <div id="chapter1" class="collapse toggle" data-parent="#display_data">
      This is Chapter 1
    </div>

    <div id="chapter2" class="collapse toggle" data-parent="#display_data">
      This is Chapter 2
    </div>

    <div id="chapter3" class="collapse toggle" data-parent="#display_data">
      This is Chapter 3
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Totally missed needing to tell inner divs who their parent was..